# Java Eclipse plugin development - using external files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing my first eclipse plugin and have  one problem. My plugin uses external jar - this works well, problem is, that this external lib uses properties file, where are stored login and properties data. Where should I copy and add this file? Now it's IO exception thrown with "Can't find the file" error.

Thanks

Comment: Does the exception tell you where it's looking for the file?  Can you tell it where to look?

Comment: No it doesn't tell and I can't tell it too. I use relative path to root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of places where a plugin can store information; which one to use is a decision based on the scope of the data and how transient or portable it should be.

- [Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_do_plug-ins_store_their_state?) is a short overview of some options.
- You can save persistent settings as Preferences; that way users can export/import them between workspaces. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_load_and_save_plug-in_preferences%3F
- You can also use [Plugin.getStateLocation()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Plugin.html#getStateLocation%28%29) to get a reference to an IPath for storing internal state of your plugin.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I solve it in UI by manually choosing the properties file. In addition, it's better solution for me, because I need to change content of properties file during the plugin run so I can reload properties when I need.